# referencing vector names dynamically via strings contained in another vector

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

A data frame **HAVE** contains a vector of identifiers called **partner** whose values are identical to other vector names in that data frame.

**HAVE:**

```
id  partner met id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 id7 id8 id9 id10
id1  id10   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id2  id6    0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id3  id7    0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id4  id9    1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id5  id8    1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id6  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id7  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id8  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id9  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id10 NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Another vector **met** indicates whether or not the respondent represented by **id** for each observation met up with their assigned **partner**. I need to store the value for **met** in the correct column **id1**-**id10**, where the column name is equivalent to **partner**. For example, the first observation should include a value of 1 in the column **id10**.

**WANT:**

```
id  partner met id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 id7 id8 id9 id10
id1  id10   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
id2  id6    0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   NA  NA  NA  NA
id3  id7    0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   NA  NA  NA
id4  id9    1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA
id5  id8    1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA
id6  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id7  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id8  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id9  NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
id10 NA     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

How can I use the value of a text variable to systematically assign values to variables with names that match the other variable's value? The true set includes **id1**-**id100**; [here's a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rvljVkqFvhKVoQ3SAFiIg4NjEzsfjNxNSfm1QRI9Pns/edit?usp=sharing) to data for a miniature example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with vectorized indexing.  Get the column index with `match` with the column names and the 'partner' column, `cbind` with row sequence to create a `matrix`, extract the elements of the dataset based on the index and assign it to 'met' column

```
nm1 <- grep("^id\\d+$", names(df1))
i1 <- !is.na(df1$partner)
df1[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1))[i1],
      match(df1$partner[i1], names(df1)[nm1]))] <- df1$met[i1]
df1
#     id partner met id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 id7 id8 id9 id10
#1   id1    id10   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    1
#2   id2     id6   0  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   0  NA  NA  NA   NA
#3   id3     id7   0  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   0  NA  NA   NA
#4   id4     id9   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   1   NA
#5   id5     id8   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   1  NA   NA
#6   id6    <NA>  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
#7   id7    <NA>  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
#8   id8    <NA>  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
#9   id9    <NA>  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
#10 id10    <NA>  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", 
"id7", "id8", "id9", "id10"), partner = c("id10", "id6", "id7", 
"id9", "id8", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), met = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), id1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), id2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), id3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), id4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), id5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), id6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    id7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), id8 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), id9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), id10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: This makes sense - I'm close. I get objects of the same length in these two cases:

**1** df1[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)),
      match(names(df1)[nm1], df1$partner))]

**2** df1$met

...but when I assign the latter to the former, I get an error: "Error in '...': 'value' is the wrong length.

It's probably a function of missingness in a more "full" example, which I didn't include. I'll revise the Q.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: your answer is helpful and makes sense, but it's producing an error. In the example I provided, I think it's because the lengths of the object `df1$met` that you assign to `df1[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)),
      match(names(df1)[nm1], df1$partner))]` are different in the original toy example I provided (10 vs 5), because the error says `value is the wrong length`. But when I add in the next 5 rows to address the issue, the error persists.

Comment: @JMQ Sorry, I think it is now fixed